# Why is $\|x+y\|^2=4 \| (x+y)/2 \|^2$ in Normed space?

Tags: normed-spaces

Why is $\|x+y\|^2=4 \| (x+y)/2 \|^2$ in normed space?

This could be an application of parallelogram law, but I don't see how.

Comment: Hint. $\|av\|=|a|\|v\|$ for any scalar $a$.

Comment: The parallellogram law only holds in inner product spaces, so cannot be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

By linearity of the norm, $\forall a \geq 0,||ax|| = a ||x||$.

$\|z\|^2 = \frac{a}{a} \|z\|^2 = a \|\frac{z}{a^2}\|^2$

Apply it for $z = x+y$ and $a = 4$.

Comment: If $a<0$ then it is $||ax|| = |a| ||x||.$

Comment: @mfl : Try, I didn't mention it, but thanks for adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\|x+y\|^2= \|2 \cdot \frac{x+y}{2}\|^2 = \left(|2|\|\frac{x+y}{2}\|\right)^2 = 4\|\frac{x+y}{2}\|^2$$

using $\|2z\|= 2\|z\|$ for all $z$